# ROS2 Navigation: Unreliable movement, Message dropping/Failed update rate/Extrapolation error

Tags: navigation, ros2, amr

Running into an issue with Autonomous navigation, on Foxy, running ROS2 with Nav2, Linorobot2 packages.

So I am running Launch->Teleop_twist->SLAM->Navigation_2 launch files. I am getting error on my Launch command window:

```
Failed to meet update rate! Took ...seconds. Try decreasing the rate, limiting sensor output frequency or limiting the number of sensors.
```

And this error on my SLAM command window:

```
Message filter dropping message: frame 'laser' at time ... for reason unknown
```

And these errors in my Navigation command window:

```
Transform data too old when converting from odom to map

Data time: ..., Transform time...

Unable to transform robot pose into global plan's frame

Extrapolation error looking up robot pose: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past
```

I think that is why in RVIZ the Navigation = Active but Localization = Inactive, so the robot does sometimes move but seems to not be following a good path or avoiding obstacles.

I read a few article that said it was related to passing odom to map at same time, or that I should put a pause into the launch file. But these linorobot2 files all seems pretty default from compared to ROS wikis so not sure how to change them.